# How to create a Dockerfile for streamlit app

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, streamlit

I am aiming to deploy a web-app written with Sreamlit,

[image: File Structure]

I can run this on my local machine by running `streamlit run Home.py` in my command line.

However, I'm not sure how to create the docker file.

Any advice?

Comment: Do you need only Dockerfile or both Dockerfile and docker-compose/`docker run`?

Comment: I need both @ΒΑΣΙΛΗΣΧΑΡΛΑΥΤΗΣ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to Dockerise your app you need two files:

1. Dockerfile         : describes the image structure,
2. docker-compose.yml : describes how to make a container from that image (`Dockerfile`)

The answer of [Javier Roger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19486986/javier-roger) is providing a very minimal Dockerfile that seems to work:

```
FROM python:3.7

# Expose port you want your app on
EXPOSE 8080

# Upgrade pip and install requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy app code and set working directory
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app

# Run
ENTRYPOINT [“streamlit”, “run”, “Home.py”, “–server.port=8080”, “–server.address=0.0.0.0”]
```

If you combine this answer with the following docker-compose then you have a nice container containing your app:

```
services:
  streamlit:
    container_name: "The name you want your container to have"
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      context: ./
    ports:
      - 'The port you want your app to have:8080'
```

Please note that both `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` should be placed in the root of your app.

To run the app just `cd` to the root dir and run:

```bash
docker compose up -d
```

if docker compose is not installed please use:

```bash
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install docker-compose-plugin
```

In case that you cannot install it so easily use this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/)

Comment: Note that you don't **need** a docker compose to build and run a docker image. Docker compose helps if you have a multi-container docker applications. Docker cli is sufficient for running single images as containers.

Comment: Yes, but in my opinion is a good practice to always use a docker-compose as it provides a gitOps way to reuse the app in a standard way no matter how long time has it past from the last time you use it. What I mean is that the only thing you need to do in order to run the app is always `docker compose up -d` (you don't need to remember any other parameter).

Answer (score 2):

This is a docker file that would work for you:

```
FROM python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8201
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run"]
CMD ["app/Home.py"]
```

This is a series of instructions and each instruction creates a layer. The base image here is `python:3.9` where you create a directory called `/app`, then copy and install everything in your `requirements.txt`. Then copy your entire folder over and  finally specify the command to run within the container. When you run the container it will be exposed on port `8201`.

Build and run the container with the following if you are going for a local set up. Run the commands from within the directory your `Dockerfile` is.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile -t app:latest .
docker run -p 8201:8201 app:latest
```

Now you will be able to access the container on your browser at `http://localhost:8201/`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
FROM python:3.7

# Expose port you want your app on
EXPOSE 8080

# Upgrade pip and install requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -U pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy app code and set working directory
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app

# Run
ENTRYPOINT [“streamlit”, “run”, “Home.py”, “–server.port=8080”, “–server.address=0.0.0.0”]
```

Comment: Thanks @javier Roger and one more thing  how to run this docker command to create the image

Comment: `docker build -t image_name:tag .`